# Jquery filtering system multiple select doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, filter, selection

I've been trying to fix the problem but i'm not that great at javascript/jquery so i'm asking you guys again.

If i select white and blue, i get all the white and blue animals, that's perfectly fine. Same as if i select Horse and Chicken... But the problem is, as soon as i select white horse or something i get random information.. The question from me is how can i fix this?

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
$('div.tags').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function()
{
var $lis = $('.results > li'),
    $checked = $('input:checked');

if ($checked.length)
{
    var selector = $checked.map(function ()
    {
        return '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
    }).get().join();

    $lis.hide().filter(selector).show().addClass("show");   
    console.log(selector)
}
else
{
    $lis.show().removeClass("show");
}
});


})
```

Html:

```
 <div class="tags">
 <fieldset class="filter-grp">
 <label><input type="checkbox" rel="white" name="year" /> white </label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" rel="blue" name="year" /> blue </label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" rel="yellow" name="year" /> yellow </label><br>
</fieldset>

<br>
<fieldset class="filter-grp">
<label><input type="checkbox" rel="horse" name="type"  /> horse</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" rel="chicken" name="type"  /> chicken</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" rel="cow" name="type"  /> cow</label><br>
</fieldset>
<br>


</div>

<ul class="results">
<li class="white cow">white cow</li>
<li class="white horse">white horse</li>
<li class="white chicken">white chicken</li>
<li class="yellow cow">yellow cow</li>
<li class="blue horse">blue horse</li>
<li class="white chicken">white chicken</li>
 </ul>
```

test here :)
http://jsfiddle.net/d6Zyr/9/

Comment: Looks like it works fine to me. The `,` in CSS selectors means **OR** not **AND**, so clicking "white" and "horse" means "everything that's white OR everything that's a horse".

Comment: While selecting  `white` n `horse` do you need only `white horse`..??

Comment: alright, is there a way to make it AND then so that if i select white and horse i only filter white horse and not everything that's white and everything that's horse??

Comment: yes A.V. that's excactly what i mean, i need to filter white horse out, not everything thats white and horse hehe

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
$('div.tags').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function () {
    var $lis = $('.results > li'),
        $checked = $('input:checked');

    if ($checked.length) {
        var selector = $checked.map(function () {
            return '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
        }).get().join();
        selector = selector.replace(",", "") // removes OR selector
        $lis.hide().filter(selector).show().addClass("show");
        console.log(selector)
    } else {
        $lis.show().removeClass("show");
    }
});


})
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d6Zyr/14/)**

Comment: Yeah just testing some things, but i see another small problem. 

if i want to filter out the yellow, white and blue horses it doesn't work properly and also if i want to select ONLY the colors it doesn't work. So lets say i wanna select all the animals that are blue and yellow.. i can't do it at the moment.

Comment: I think you may need to introduce another selector to switch between `OR` and `AND` conditions.. . Else just check all animal names and then required colors for the case you mentioned..

Comment: well you might be able to take a look on this page ( it might be a foreign language but at least you can see what i mean ) http://berckmans-designs.nl/filternew/

Comment: This is working same as my updated fiddle.. isn't it..?? Or am i missing anything??

Comment: hmm.. i think it is yeah, is there an easier way to filter? i mean i dont have any knowledge of jquery or javascript, just trying to create something i actualy don't understand... so i't quite hard for me to understand what you mean with introduce another switch.

Comment: To be fair... i dont understand it, but that's because jquery and javascript is hocus pocus... i've found this earlier today and it has what i need ( like endless multiple selection possibility's ) but the thing is... i need to pull information from a database, put that in a list ( not to difficult ) and then be able to filter this through sort of a system we've just created... http://jiren.github.com/filter.js/filterjs.html <-- what is found..

Comment: A.V. i got a better desciption of what i need... http://berckmans-designs.nl/filternew/index1.php if you take a look of that... i need to be able to select 2 colors or 2 races and it still has to work.